# Direction array to support multiple keydowns in 4-directional movement

Tags: javascript

To get a simple, responsive, 4-directional movement in a 2D game, I've implemented the following. When a key is pressed, the `add` method adds the direction to the `keys` array. When the key is released, the `remove` method removes the direction from the `keys` array. In my `Update` method, I call `getLast` to get the last direction and move the player in that direction.

I want to restrict movement to one direction, but when I press multiple keys, I want the last key's direction to be used. Basically, if I'm going left and press up, but then release up while still holding down left, I want the character to go left, up, and continue going left.

I'm rather inexperienced when it comes to this kind of Javascript, so I'm hoping anyone has some tips / best practices recommendations for this small code snippet. I know naming is a bit iffy - I wanted to name it 'stack', but it's hardly a stack implementation.

```
function Keys() {
    this.keys = [];
}

// Only add the direction if it doesn't exist yet
Keys.prototype.add = function (dir) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.keys.length; i++) {
        if (this.keys[i] == dir) {
            return;
        }
    }

    this.keys[this.keys.length] = dir;
};

// Find the index of the first occurrence and splice the array there without it
Keys.prototype.remove = function (dir) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.keys.length; i++) {
        if (this.keys[i] == dir) {
            this.keys.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};

Keys.prototype.getLast = function () {
    if (this.keys.length > 0) {
        return this.keys[this.keys.length - 1];
    }
};
```

In my main file, I use it as: `var keys = new Keys();`

Comment: Why do you need an array for this?

Comment: I couldn't really think of a different way. I want to restrict movement to one direction, but when I press multiple keys, I want the last key's direction to be used. I was probably over-thinking it, but an alternative solution doesn't come to mind. Basically, if I'm going left and press up, but then release up while still holding down left, I want the character to go left, up, and continue going left.

Comment: Great, I was beginning to think I made an unnecessary solution to a problem that didn't exist! I'll add my comment to the post, to clarify a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support IE8 and under, you could cut out those for-loops by using [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
// Only add the direction if it doesn't exist yet
Keys.prototype.add = function (dir) {
    if (!~this.keys.indexOf(dir)) {
        // you could also do this.keys.indexOf(dir) == -1
        this.keys[this.keys.length] = dir;
    }
};

// Find the index of the first occurrence and splice the array there without it
Keys.prototype.remove = function (dir) {
    // you could also save this in a variable to use the second time
    if (~this.keys.indexOf(dir)) {
        this.keys.splice(this.keys.indexOf(dir), 1);
    }
};
```

Instead of `this.keys[this.keys.length] = dir;`, you could just `push()`:

```
this.keys.push(dir);
```

Your check in `Keys.prototype.getLast` is redundant. It'll either return an item from the array, or nothing (`undefined`). A nonexistant array index also returns `undefined`, so you could just cut it out:

```
Keys.prototype.getLast = function () {
    return this.keys[this.keys.length - 1];
};
```

If you need to support oldIE, you could at least optimize `Keys.prototype.remove` by adding a `return` statement after removing the item:

```
Keys.prototype.remove = function (dir) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.keys.length; i++) {
        if (this.keys[i] == dir) {
            this.keys.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression `push()` would _prepend_ the item. This is the first time I've seen the `~` operator, very interesting!

Comment: @IvoCoumans, don't use it like this, it hurts readability. Use `indexOf(dir) >= 0` (or `contains(dir)` in ES6).